# Reply to ping while having another hostname

Tags: linux, ping, hostname

I have a device which is normally connected to the internet, but for test purposes, it's now connected directly to a nic of my PC. The device pings a hostname by means of a connectivity test.

While my PC has another hostname, is it possible to reply to the ping request of the device?

Currently the OS is linux, but a windows solution is welcome also. Adding additional hardware is fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

ICMP uses IP addresses to communicate; not hostnames.  If you specify a hostname, the pinging machine attempts to lookup the IP of the specified host.

For more info, check out the Wikipedia article.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

This is about the IP of your PC's NIC. You need to tell your device where to ping. By a casual connection over the NIC, both ends should get a link-local IP like `169.254.73.253`. To check your PC's IP, connect the device and start the connection in Linux. Then check `ifconfig`. Once you know the PC's IP, you need to set it in the device as the ping's target or associate it with the hostname there.

By a more complex Linux setup, there will be a DHCP server on the Linux side that assigns IP to the device. This is similar to the former. Check the PC's IP with `ifconfig` and configure it as the target on the device.

Comment: Unfortunately the target is hardcoded in the firmware of the device. It's currently not possible to change it.